# What is best multi-user database C# app approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to know what is the best method for developing a multi-user C# app using the SQL Server2005 as database. This is what I have in mind:

1. using nhibernate or telerik's openacces orm.
2. linq
3. using wrappers. all data from tables load into corresponding objects (at startup) and from    that point only delete&update transactions affect the database.
4. ...

I've looked at orm tools but in my opinion they generate a lot of code and i do not know if 
it's necessary.

What is the best solution having in mind future changes in the application?
If i would choose the 3rd option how can i ensure that only one users modifies a row in a table(how can i lock a table row which is under modification) ?
Any suggestions or reading material will help!
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure that loading ALL data is a good decision... But it depends on you database size...

Comment: What do you mean by "linq"? Do you mean "LINQ to SQL"? Be sure to consider Entity Framework.

Comment: @John Saunders - you were reading my mind.  LINQ is much more encompassing than just sql (LINQ is integrated with many types of datasources including collections, XML and much more).

Answer (score 1):

If it's multiuser do NOT do #3.  The purpose of an DBMS is to handle the multi-user aspects for you.  Everything from transactions to access rights are built right in.  Going down the path of mimicking that in your code will be difficult to get right.  In the past some "engines" like Borland's BDE and MS Access did this.  The end result is that you end up dealing with little things like data corruption and consistency errors.

Never mind that as your database grows the is going to take exponentially longer to start.

We typically stay away from ORM tools for a number of reasons, mostly feature / benefit / security concerns.  Of course, we are extremely well versed in SQL and can take advantage of the specific features a given db server can offer, which most ORMs can't do.  We also tend to tweak the queries based on performance metrics after product release, which would force a recompile of an app for most ORMs.  By staying away from this, we can let production DBAs do their job.  That may or may not be a concern of yours.

That said a lot of dev teams both like and successfully use the ones you spoke about.  I would say to skip Linq-to-SQL in favor of Entity Framework if you're going that route.  Linq-to-SQL has all but been replaced by EF.

Comment: am I correct in assuming you mean skip LINQ-to-sql (and not just LINQ)?  If so - I completely agree.

Comment: @RQDQ: Yes, LINQ itself is pretty good; however I mean skip LINQ-to-SQL.  Which was basically replaced by EF.  Edited to clarify.

Comment: EF's T-SQL generation (for SQL Server) is pretty decent now (in v4).  Just don't mention v1!

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of ways to solve this, but don't discount ORM.  Microsoft's [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) is getting better with every revision. The framework 4.0 bits are pretty good and play extremely well with LINQ.

As for generated code vs your own, try something like [Entity Spaces](http://entityspaces.net/)... You have complete control over how the code gets generated and the data access layer is extremely powerful and flexible (not to mention very easy to use).  It also plays nicely with LINQ.

I have written a lot of data access code over the years.  In the beginning, the ORM tools were rough around the edges and left a lot to be desired.  These tools have gone through many iterations since and have become indispensable in my opinion.  I can't imagine writing routine after routine that does the same basic CRUD.  I did that for years and spent lots of time correcting hardcoded SQL and vow to avoid it at all costs from here on out.

As for concurrency / locking issues, that's a question unto itself.  There are many ways to provide locking (the major categories being optimistic and pessimistic).   Each has its pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a load of effort and time and use an ORM. In terms of helping you decide which one, there is loads of information/opinion on the web (and StackOverflow!) about which one to use but that'll depend on what your application requirements are (which you haven't described).

I like Linq-to-SQL for small/mid sized apps. It's quick and easy and almost efficient. For bigger apps it'll depend on what types of data transformations and design you have in mind but Linq-to-Entities or nHibernate are probably the most appropriate.